# Copy vector of type 'bar to vector of type BYTE

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a member vector `std::vector<BYTE> memberVec`

In an internal member function I have an `std::vector` of structs of type `bar` which contain four `double` values each.
I need to copy the content fo std::vector byte by byte into `std::vector<BYTE> foo`.

This is what I do now, and I would really appreciate it, if you show me a more C++ style approach:

```
    typedef struct{
        double dX1, dY1, dX2, dY2;
    }bar;

        std::vector<bar> oBar;
        //fill  obar
        memberVec.resize(oBar.size()*sizeof(double) * 4);
        BYTE* pData = (BYTE*)&memberVec[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < oBar.size(); i++)
        {
            memcpy(pData, &oBar[i].dX1, sizeof(double));
            pData += sizeof(double);
            memcpy(pData, &oBar[i].dY1, sizeof(double));
            pData += sizeof(double);
            memcpy(pData, &oBar[i].dX2, sizeof(double));
            pData += sizeof(double);
            memcpy(pData, &oBar[i].dY2, sizeof(double));
            pData += sizeof(double);

        }
```

Comment: @Ajay I need to have a BYTE vector at the end, how else would I copy the bar vectors content to it?

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
memberVec.assign(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(oBar.data()),
                 reinterpret_cast<const char*>(oBar.data() + oBar.size()));
```

Comment: Such designs are prone to error, and any crept-in bugs are hard to find.

Comment: data member only exists in C++11 unfortunately

Comment: @tzippy It's equivilent to `&oBar[0]`

Comment: Using `&oBar.front()` instead

Comment: @Ajay compared to the version where you have one `memcpy` per struct member per element in vector, this is holidays :)

Comment: @Drax, invalid structure alignments will make your holidays short, and would cancel further bigger holidays. `struct A { int, char, float}` is such example.

Comment: @Ajay True, but well this is probably gonna be unserialised in the same structure on the same or equivalent machine, binary protocols are not portable anyway. You might save some space with the first version, but you can always fall back to it if that code part performance is needed more then the clarity that one line of code brings compared to ten.

Comment: @Ajay: There's no problem with copying data from a (correctly aligned) structure into an array of bytes. There's only an issue if you try to reinterpret that byte array as something other than a byte array, rather than properly deserialising it, and there's no indication that that's happening.